# Programmatic access to new Publishing Pages that haven't been checked in

Tags: 2013, development

Is it possiblet o get a list of Publishing Pages in a Pages library that have been created, but haven't been checked in after initially creating the page?

`SPList.ItemCount` does give the correct amount of items, including these pages that have been created but not even checked in once. However, `SPList.GetItems` query ignores those pages - also `SPList.Items` collection ignores these pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, they give you a means in the Library Settings to check for files with no checked in version. I don't know what that is using under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

I commonly use:

```
if (file.CheckOutType != SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
{
    file.CheckIn("Programmatically Checked In");
}
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called `CheckedOutFiles` on the Document Library.  Additionally you can grab the publishing status via the `SPModerationInformation` property on the page like so:

```
SPModerationInformation moderationInformation= page.ListItem.ModerationInformation;
if (moderationInformation.Status == SPModerationStatusType.Pending)
```

[See here for a detailed description of CheckedOutFiles](http://paddyt.blogspot.com/2012/05/spdocuementlibrarycheckedoutfiles.html) or [here for an example of publishing all unpublished pages using SPModerationInformation](https://dkolitha.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/publishing-pages-check-in-file-programmatically/).

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize [Moderation Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh644558%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
Value:3 The list item is in the draft or checked out state.
```

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve items in the draft or checked out state:

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Pages");
var query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus'/><Value Type='Number'>3</Value></Eq></Where>";
var items = list.GetItems(query);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't work as list.GetItems without _ModerationStatus filter doesn't return the items as they have never been checked in.